# Is it possible to view exact google map in Android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have created a mapview application and it shows map without any problem. But when I compare this map with the "Maps" application in the Android phone, there is some mismatch in the places. Some places are not shown in my application. I think the "Maps" application shows exactly the same as Google map. How to load the same map in my application also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Google Maps application uses a different tiles provider than the MapView in the Android SDK. You'll notice that the tiles (squares on the map) are of much higher quality in the Google Maps application. Third party developers cannot use embed these high quality tiles in their applications.

You'll notice other subtle differences as well (ex: street names get aligned correctly when moving the map, whereas they are static in the Android MapView SDK tiles provider).

Besides the actual tiles themselves, the loading of the tiles, and the touch gestures used to pan and zoom the map are also implemented much better on the official Google Maps application.